# Is there a way to detect the insertion of a new row in SQL?

Tags: c#, sql, database

I have a program in C# which allows users to send and receive text messages, the server receiving incoming texts parses the messages then puts them into an SQL database, and I was wondering if there was a way I could detect the insertion of a new row into this database, and fire an event which notifies the user of a new incoming message?

Comment: Yes they're called [SQL Triggers](http://www.sqlteam.com/article/an-introduction-to-triggers-part-i)

Comment: Yes. [Triggers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_trigger) run in response to add/edit/delete of rows.

Comment: Depends on the **actual database** (SQL is just a query language - used by many databases - not a database product in itself) that you're using - but many support the concept of **triggers**

Comment: Does your application inserts into DB directly, or through some Web Service?

Comment: You could look into using SqlDependency. However, this is all highly dependent on the database you are using.

Comment: This question is overly vague.

Comment: Would I be able to run c# code based on a certain condition doing this?

Comment: no I have a windows service which inserts into SQL, the client program then fetches the texts from that database

Answer (score 5):

I prorpose that u use the [SqlDependency](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldependency.aspx) class.

Here's some sample code:

It's a long read, but I suggest you have a look at the following MSDN [article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a52dhwx7%28v=vs.80%29.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to use the Windows Service which will monitor the messages added in the SQL Server database and then fire the appropriate action. Another way will be using MSMQ where you can send the message to MSMQ once inserted in the database. Have a table

```
               User Id , MessageCount  Last Message DateTime
                1           2             1/1/2014 12:30
```

and update this table when you get the message.

Answer (score -1):

Of course there is. You can write a trigger or you can use Change Data Capture mechanism.

Comment: ***IF*** (and only if) the OP says `sql` and means `sql-server` - CDC is a SQL Server specific feature

Comment: If he is writing in C# there is highly possible that this is just the Sql Server

Answer (score -1):

Why don't you try CLR Triggers?

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms254959%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

You can fire the event from the CLR Procedure.

Although this is not the way to go about it. These messages should be put into a ServiceBus queue and processed asynchronously on a separate thread or process(Such as a worker role in Azure?)

Comment: I didn't downvote, but this assumes they are using SQL server.

Comment: SQLDependency Class also expects you to have Sql server IIRC?

Comment: It does, but what does that have to do with your question?

Answer (score -2):

SQL trigger after insert

> http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189799.aspx

Taking into account the comment below, my answer is still the same:

> http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/341680/Using-Triggers-in-Csharp-and-Sql-Server

And similar question asked here:

> [On table update, trigger an action in my .NET code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18318178/on-table-update-trigger-an-action-in-my-net-code)

Comment: Trigger mechanism isn't really what OP needs, i think he wants a C# event which will be triggered after SQL insertion.

Comment: I downvoted for both the patronising tone of your answer and that there's no actual substance to this answer, just a bunch of links.

Comment: The question should have been closed anyway due to lack of research. A simple Google returned millions of possible results and ways to accomplish this. Dumb questions deserve dumb answers.

Comment: No, they don't. Just because someone planted some weeds in the garden doesn't mean you have to look after them. A constructive approach would have been to post your duplicate as a comment.